# bootstrap validator date range using variables

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, validation, date-range

I am trying to validate a `date range` using [bootstrap validator](http://formvalidation.io/).
The problem is that I need to specify the `min` and `max` condition dynamically using variables.

Here's what I did but failed. Not sure how to use variables to specify the ranges in bootstrap validator?

```
<?php
$min_date = "2014-02-01";
$max_date = "2014-02-28";
?>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var min_date = '<?php echo $min_date; ?>'; <-- This works! Thank you Dennis!
var max_date = '<?php echo $max_date; ?>'; <-- This works! Thank you Dennis!

$('#form')

 .bootstrapValidator({
            feedbackIcons: {
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                'date': {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Required'
                        },
                        date: {
                            message: 'The date is not valid',
                            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                            min: min_date,         <-- this does not work
                            max: max_date          <-- this does not work
                            //min: '2014-02-01',   <-- this works
                            //max: '2014-02-28'    <-- this works
                        }
                    }
                }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try to not declare the variables between ´$('#form')´ and  ´.bootstrapValidator({´

Comment: Thank you, but still no luck.

Comment: And now put ' or " (quotes) before and behind your PHP-Tags in the assign.

Comment: Now it's recognized by the validator, but the validator always yields error( 'The date is not valid' ) regardless of what date I choose...

Comment: Try `var min_date = new Date('<?php echo $min_date; ?>');` (and same for `var max_date ...`